# How can I get the the selected visual content of a TabControl?

Tags: wpf

My custom TabControl uses a ContentTemplate in order to show the selected content.  From within the TabControl, how can I get the actual Visual Content?  SelectedTabItem.Content is my viewmodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected content presenter is a templated part of TabControl, so we can do this in our subclass:

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        _selectedContentHost = Template.FindName("PART_SelectedContentHost", this) as ContentPresenter;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [`TabControl` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.aspx) and [`TabItem` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabitem.aspx) pages at MSDN, you will see that they both extend the [`System.Windows.Media.Visual` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.aspx). Therefore the whole object *is* the `Visual` object and can be used as a parameter in any method that takes a `Visual` object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sheridan.  The problem is that it's a HeaderContentControl, and only the header content is in the visual tree for each item.